# How can I extract redirected url with Python without using requests module and via xpath?

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, python-requests

The html-page incudes the following script:

```
<script>
const url = 'REQUIRED LINK';
window.location.href = url + window.location.search;
</script>
```

This is the only place in page, where the link is.
I don't know Java at all.
I tried extract this way:

```
page_2 = requests.get(link).content.decode('UTF-8')
html_tree = html.fromstring(page_2)

inside_scripts = html_tree.xpath("//script[contains(@text, 'url')]")
```

But it returns empty list.

Comment: Java =/= Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use:

```
inside_scripts = html_tree.xpath("//script[contains(., 'url')]")
```

Comment: I am not an expert in html but I believe this is related with xpath definition.

Comment: `@text` means you're looking for an attribute. script element has no attribute. I suppose you were looking for this : `//script[contains(text(),"const url")]`

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose `const url = 'REQUIRED LINK';` always uses the same formatting, including spaces.

You could run the following code - using regex - to extract `'REQUIRED LINK'`

**Javascript:**

```
const regex = /(?<=const url = ').+(?=';)/gm;

var required_link = YOUR_HTML_STRING.match(regex);
```

**Python:**

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=const url = ').+(?=';)"

require_link = re.findall(regex, HTML_STRING)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner to extract it with XPath 1.0 :

```
print(html_tree.xpath('substring-after(substring-before(//script[contains(.,"const url")],"';"),"= '")'))
```

Output : `REQUIRED LINK`